# Dart web audio noteOn internal error

Tags: audio, dart, dart-html

I'm trying to get dart to play an audio, but everytime I try to play the Audio I get the following error:

```
Internal error: 'dart:_blink': error: line 248: native function 'AudioBufferSourceNode_noteOn_Callback_RESOLVER_STRING_1_double' (2 arguments) cannot be found
Native_AudioBufferSourceNode_noteOn_Callback(mthis, when) native "AudioBufferSourceNode_noteOn_Callback_RESOLVER_STRING_1_double";
```

This is the my Audio class:

```dart
class Audio {

  static List<Audio> _loadQueue = new List<Audio>();

  String _url;
  bool loaded = false;
  AudioBufferSourceNode _source;

  Audio(this._url) {
    if (audioContext == null) {
      _loadQueue.add(this);
    }
    else {
      load();
    }
  }

  void load() {
    print("Loading sound: " + _url);
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", _url);
    req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    req.onLoad.listen((e) {
      _source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
      print("Found sound: " + _url + ". Decoding...");
      audioContext.decodeAudioData(req.response).then((buffer) {
        _source.buffer = buffer;
        _source.connectNode(gainNode);
        _source.connectNode(audioContext.destination);
        loaded = true;
      });
    });

    req.send();
  }

  void play() {
    if (!loaded) { return; }
    _source.noteOn(0);
  }

  void stop() {
    if (!loaded) return;
    _source.noteOff(0);
  }

  static void loadAll() {

    _loadQueue.forEach((e) {e.load();});
  }
}
```

The audio context and gain node is created in another class like this:

```dart
audioContext = new AudioContext();
gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
gainNode.connectNode(audioContext.destination);

Audio.loadAll();
```

I don't know what the problem is, especially since it says it's internal, and that it's missing arguments, but the noteOn function only takes one argument.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Would you please report at http://dartbug.com/new

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue using dart 1.6. It seems noteOn has been replaced by start in the latest spec/implementation.

- The AudioBufferSourceNode Interface (http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#the-audiobuffersourcenode-interface)
- Porting notes (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Porting_webkitAudioContext_code_to_standards_based_AudioContext#Changes_to_methods_used_to_start.2Fstop_AudioBufferSourceNode_and_OscillatorNode)